# ¿Cómo repetir solo vocales o solo consonates en Python, dado un string?

Tags: python

qué tal, tengo esta pregunta, se pide lo siguiente:
Repetir 2 veces las vocales o las consonates según se pida, y separar cada letra.

1. Manzana (vocales)
   el resultado debe ser: M AA N Z AA N AA
2. Mora (consonantes)
   el resultado debe ser: MM O RR A

Yo solo pude conseguir duplicarlos asi

```
>>> s = '  Manzana '.upper()
>>> n = 2
>>> ''.join([char*n for char in s])
```

¿cómo podría hacer que me salga el resultado que se pide?. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Interesante ejercicio! Yo lo abordaría de la siguiente manera:

```
VOWELS = set('AEIOU')

def repeat_letters(string, condition):
    return ' '.join(
        2 * letter if condition(letter) else letter
        for letter in string.upper()
    )
```

Y para obtener uno u otro tipo de resultado, invocaría la función de la siguiente manera:

```
>>> repeat_letters('Manzana', lambda letter: letter in VOWELS)
'M AA N Z AA N AA'
>>> repeat_letters('Mora', lambda letter: letter not in VOWELS)
'MM O RR A'
```

De esta manera tenemos los siguientes elementos resaltantes:

En primer lugar, definimos una constante donde están las vocales, que sirva para verificar si una letra es, en efecto, una vocal o, por lo contrario, si no lo es. (con un `set()` para que estas verificaciones se hagan en tiempo constante)

Segundo, como la diferencia entre uno y otro tipo de resultado esperado depende de una condición, me parece buena idea que la función que estamos creando esté preparada para recibir un *callable* que contenga dichas condiciones. Recordemos la manera más expedita para crear *callables* en Python, es a través de `lambda`. ¿Por qué un *callable*? Porque es lo que nos permitirá evaluar cada letra de manera dinámica.

Luego, dentro de la [expresión generadora](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) que pasamos como argumento a `join`, nos valemos de un [expresión condicional](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (u operador ternario, como suele llamarse) para decidir si cada letra debe ser repetida o no, de acuerdo a si la condición pasada como argumento devuelve `True` al ser evaluada con una letra en particular. Acá usamos una operación de multiplicación de strings por enteros, la cual devuelve la string en cuestión repetida n veces (en este caso, 2 veces)

Comment: Elegante! No habría pensado en hacer un set!